# PHP: View a function from an include file

Tags: php

Let's say my PHP file has

```
<?php
    include 'function.php';
    // CODE I CAN WRITE BELOW
    ...
?>
```

Is there any way to view a particular function within that file. Let's say there was a function:

```
function add($a,$b) {return $a+$b;}
```

Can I then print the function to the user so they can see what it looks like in the include file? It would be good if I could actually say, look, here's the source code of the entire include file without using `show_source` or similar as `open_basedir` is in effect so I can't

Full script

```
error_reporting(0);

include 'function.php';

$dir = 'sandbox/' . sha1($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) . '/';

if(!file_exists($dir)){
  mkdir($dir);
}

switch ($_GET["action"] ?? "") {
  case 'pwd':
    echo $dir;
    break;
  case 'upload':
    $data = $_GET["data"] ?? "";
    file_put_contents("$dir" . "index.php", $data);
  case 'shell':
    initShellEnv($dir);
    include $dir . "index.php";
    break;
  default:
    highlight_file(__FILE__);
    break;
}
```

Comment: you can do something like print(add($a,$b))

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. The `include` statement is used to **execute** code. `show_source()` is used to generate syntax highlighting. You can't read files from disallowed locations. How does this all match together, what's your ultimate goal?

Comment: @George done this and found the line but can't print the function definition.

Comment: Normally, showing the source code to the user would be considered a security risk. What is the purpose of your program exactly?

Comment: @HassaanAli that prints out the result, not the definition of the function

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why `show_source` wouldn't work - you say open_basedir is enabled, but as far as I know that also affects `include`, which sounds like it's working. If you can include a file, you can definitely read it.

Comment: Have updated with full script

Comment: Hmmm... Make a new section similar to `default`, replacing `highlight_file(__FILE__);` with `highlight_file('function.php');`?

Comment: highlight_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/html/function.php) is not within the allowed path(s):

Remember - the file that is being run is in /var/www/html/sandbox/{sha1value}/index.php

Comment: Then the code you've shared is not really relevant I guess. If you've set a directive so you can only access files within a given list of directories, you can only access files within a given list of directories. That's the point. It's also worth noting that `include` won't work either (but `include` doesn't throw errors on failure and you have `error_reporting(0);` so perhaps you haven't noticed it doesn't work).

Comment: I can set error_reporting(1) so it does highlight errors. How is the code I shared not relevant? There is away around this but I don't know what it is

Comment: @pee2pee why do you think there's a way round it? With open_basedir you've specifically told PHP it cannot access these files. Therefore, it cannot access these files. If there was a way around that, what would be the point of the restriction? As far as I can see the only way to solve your issue would be to change the open_basedir config.